C++ Undeclared Identifier (Forward Declaration)
I'm kinda new at coding but I would like to ask why this doesn't work. I prefer putting all the definitions below so I tried coding this but for some reason it didn't work.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void ParentClass::Word();
void ParentClass::Word2();

int main() {
    ParentClass Parent;
    Parent.Word();
    Parent.Word2();
}

class ParentClass {
public:
    void Word() {
        std::cout << "Parent \n";
    }

    void Word2() {
        std::cout << "Parent2 \n";
    }
};

I expected it to work the same as when I put the class before the main function but it unfortunately didnt. It just have a red underline on:

void ParentClass::Word();
void ParentClass::Word2();


You'd make your life so much easier if you just declared ParentClass first..

The ParentClass::Word references a static method called Word in the ParentClass class.  The () means to call/envoke the method.  Word is not a static method, and you cannot evoke it because you did not forward declare ParentClass (you don't have to forward declare the methods of that class)

You cannot forward declare a method of a class (only the class itself). But in this case as mentioned above there's no need to, because ParentClass can be located above main.

In C++ everything needs to be declared before in can be referenced. You need to define the class first (a definition is necessary for the members to be declared), then you can define the member functions in the end of the file

When your C++ compiler sees void ParentClass::Word(); it has no way of knowing whether ParentClass is a class or namespace or macro or something else.  The compiler reads your file from beginning to end - it will not jump around the file to see if that line makes more sense after compiling later lines.

Voted to reopen. "caused by typos"? No, clearly, the code was deliberate, and not obviously wrong to a beginner. The underlying problem is misunderstanding the rules for forward declarations.

Unfortunately, because of that totally inappropriate closure, I have to answer in a comment. You can't forward-declare members of a class. The definition of the class has to occur before any use of names defined inside that class.

In short, every single name your use must be introduced by a declaration. This includes the name ParentClass. The next thing is that, the only way to introduce the name Word as a member function is to provide a definition of the class ParentClass. A forward declaration of ParentClass won't suffice.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>    
    
class ParentClass {
    public:
        // Declaration of the member function 'Word' of ParentClass
        void Word();
        // Declaration of the member function 'Word2' of ParentClass
        void Word2();
};

// The main function where the execution of the program begins
int main() {
    // Create an instance of ParentClass named 'Parent'
    ParentClass Parent;
    // Call the 'Word' method on the 'Parent' object
    Parent.Word();
    // Call the 'Word2' method on the 'Parent' object
    Parent.Word2();

    return 0;
}

// Definition of the 'Word' method for ParentClass
void ParentClass::Word() {
    std::cout << "Parent \n";
}

// Definition of the 'Word2' method for ParentClass
void ParentClass::Word2() {
    std::cout << "Parent2 \n";
}

In practice, it is common to separate the declaration and definition of classes and their member functions into multiple files for better organization and maintainability.
ParentClass.h file
#ifndef PARENTCLASS_H
#define PARENTCLASS_H


class ParentClass {
    public:
        // Declaration of the member function 'Word' of ParentClass
        void Word();
        // Declaration of the member function 'Word2' of ParentClass
        void Word2();
};

#endif // PARENTCLASS_H

ParentClass.cpp file
#include "ParentClass.h" // Include the header that contain declaration
#include <iostream>

// Definition of the 'Word' method for ParentClass
void ParentClass::Word() {
    std::cout << "Parent \n";
}

// Definition of the 'Word2' method for ParentClass
void ParentClass::Word2() {
    std::cout << "Parent2 \n";
}

main.cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include "ParentClass.h"

// The main function where the execution of the program begins
int main() {
    // Create an instance of ParentClass named 'Parent'
    ParentClass Parent;
    // Call the 'Word' method on the 'Parent' object
    Parent.Word();
    // Call the 'Word2' method on the 'Parent' object
    Parent.Word2();

    return 0;
}


What you're looking for when forward declaring with a class is to forward declare the class and its member functions, and then define the member functions later.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class ParentClass {
public:
    void Word();
    void Word2();
};

int main() {
    ParentClass Parent;
    Parent.Word();
    Parent.Word2();
}

void ParentClass::Word() {
    std::cout << "Parent \n";
}

void ParentClass::Word2() {
    std::cout << "Parent2 \n";
}

